# Shared Hudson installation - how to enable access to git over ssh?

Tags: git, hudson

We are trying to set up a Hudson server and share it between different projects. Hudson authenticates users against our Windows domain AD, and the project based security matrix makes it easy to manage who can access which projects.

Remaining issue is, that most of the projects use git over ssh. Is there a way to make shared Hudson access git so that each project could create and manage their own jobs without compromising security?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is running on a Linux or windows box so I will give you answers for both.

Linux
If installing through a package (rpm in my case), a user is created with a custom home directory for Hudson.  This defaults to /var/lib/hudson.  All you need to do for git ssh to work is create a folder /var/lib/hudson/.ssh and copy your id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files to there.

Windows
Windows is very similar.  Set the git location in your main configuration (Ort node configuration if slave) in hudson to be full path to Git (IE C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe).  Then create the same .ssh folder at the root of the git folder (IE C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\.ssh) and copy in the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files.